# How to extract a particular message from IBM MQ

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I can extract message from my remote mq but I want to extract a particular message from remote mq . Currently I am extracting all message then I'm searching for particular string into MQSTR message from mq . But I don't want to search after downloading the message . Is there any way that I can search particular string from remote mq side . Currently my code in C#

Comment: You can use a selector to perform a selective GET based on fields of the MQMD or based on message properties, but not based on a string in the actual message.

Comment: you could solve this by having a ReplayServer on the remote site. It stores all your messages on file and let's you search for it by content. Like a database for messaging. But ReplayServer is not free, it's a commercial product (I work on it).

Comment: The easiest way would be to browse your messages before getting them. However if you're having a large number of messages it can be costly (much CPU to parse the message strings for what you're looking for.) A better solution is to use the message ID as get criterion.